# Form is not being processed, page immediately redirects

Tags: php, forms, redirect

I just need a reality check.  This page is redirecting to the HTTP_HOST immediately without downloading data or processing the form.  It was, at one time working.  I broke something but I'm blind to it.
I'm hitting the page with a query that has 1 value pair, like this:  http://Nitrofill.biz/tr/Nitrofill_Presentation?num=EV4ghF8p3

Can anybody help me spot the problem?

```
<?php session_start();
require_once('Connect.php') ;
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><title>Nitrofill Document</title>

<?php

$sn=$_GET['num'];
echo $sn;

mysql_connect($hostname,$username, $password) OR die('Unable to connect to database! Please try again later.');
mysql_select_db($dbname);
 $selectSQL = "select * from `Presentations` where `serialnum` ='" . $sn ."'" ;

$result = mysql_query($selectSQL) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result,  MYSQL_BOTH);
$thedoc = urldecode($row['docurl']);
$therecip=urldecode($row['recipient']);
$thetracker=urldecode($row['tracker']);
$lastacc=urldecode($row['last_accessed']);

?>
</head>
<body>

<form id="notice" action="http://m3sglobal.com/gdform.php" method="post"> 
<input  name="subject" value="<?php echo $therecip . " has viewed the document you sent them.";?> " /> 
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="<?php echo $thedoc ; ?>"/>
<label>Email:</label><input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $thetracker ; ?>"/>
<label>Comments:</label><textarea name="comments" cols="40" rows="5">
Document Viewed:<?php echo $thedoc ; ?>

When Accessed:<?php echo $lastacc ; ?>
</textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `.php` in the link you have posted. It needs to be

```
http://nitrofill.biz/tr/Nitrofill_Presentation.php?num=EV4ghF8p3
```

Comment: THANKYOU!  Now, isn't it weird that I couldn't see that?  So simple and obvious, but I"ve been hung up on it for a couple of hours!.